# How do you test that a string is the empty string

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

How do you test that a string str is the empty string? 
Below is the code I tried, but when I just hit enter on eclipse console, it does not print right output which should be "String is Null"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    out.print("Press Y to continue: ");
    String yes= in.next();
    int LengthOfInput = yes.length();
    if (LengthOfInput==0)
    {
        out.print("String is Null");
    }
    else {
        out.print("String not null");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you print out what yes contains, (between quotes) or print out the bytes in the char array of the String? Please debug before asking, and show the results of your debugging in your question.

Comment: Do try your code on terminal instead of IDE console.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, with `import static System.out;` you can simply use `out`

Comment: `import static java.lang.System.out;`

Comment: Are you asking specifically about how to test for an empty string, or did you **really** want to know how to detect when a user typed nothing in response to a request for input?

Comment: Java conventions say not to name variables, such as `LengthOfInput`, beginning with uppercase letters. It will no break your code, but anybody skimming the code who missed the declaration will assume it's the name of a class, and that's also why it looks blue in StackOverflow's pretty print, because it assumes it is a Class name. It is better to follow the convention and start variables with a lowercase letter.

Comment: If you think an answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method correctly identifies whether a string is empty. Other than this method, you can also call `isEmpty` on a string or check of the string is equal to `""`

```
if (string.isEmpty())

if (string.equals(""))
```

The reason why your code did not work as expected is because you read the user input wrongly. `next` method by default will not return an empty string because it will always try to find something to read.

To achieve your intended behaviour call `nextLine` instead of `next`.